# Where to use 960 css clear class

Tags: css, frameworks, 960.gs

I don't understand why I should use clear class in 960 css framework. In any example I remove div with class clear it works fine. could you tell me the usage and the purpose of that class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sure floating elements wont exist to the left or right of the element with the class (if you have any float elements that might cause a layout you weren't after).

Also worth a search on google is clearfix